# Calling scanf from assembly for float segfaults instead of returning the floats in xmm registers

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, scanf, x86-64

I need to write a program in assembly that needs to get some user arguments using `scanf`. The problem is that in the third call, I get segmentation fault.

Briefly about the program purpose.
It should get input from the user in this format:

```
epsilon = 1.0e-8
order = 2
coeff 2 = 2.0 0.0
coeff 1 = 5.0 0.0
coeff 0 = 3.0 0.0
initial = 5.0 0.0
coeff 0 = 3.0 0.0
```

and store this data in data structures.

---

String formats:

```
    section .data
    epsilon_format:
    db "epsilon = %g",0
    order_format:
    db " order = %d",0
    coeff_format:
    db " coeff %d = %le %le",0
    initial_format:
    db " initial = %le %le"
    root_format:
    db "root = %.17g %.17g", 10, 0
    divide_by_zero:
    db "divide by zero",10,0
```

Code:

```
main:
call    **get_input**
call    newton_raphson
call    show_output

mov rdi, [poly_real]
call    free
mov rdi, [poly_img]
call    free
mov rdi, [deriv_img]
call    free
mov rdi, [deriv_real]
call    free

mov rax, 60
syscall
```

Calling `scanf` function:

```
get_input:
mov rdi, epsilon_format
mov rax, 1
;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 call   scanf             ;first call --- works fine
;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
movsd   qword [epsilon], xmm0 ;epsilon
mov rdi, order_format
mov rsi, order
mov rax,0
call    scanf       ;order

mov r10, [order]
inc r10

mov rax, 8
mul r10
mov rdi, rax
call    malloc
mov [poly_real], rax 

mov r10, [order]
inc r10
mov rax, 8
mul r10
mov rdi, rax
call    malloc
mov [poly_img], rax


mov r10, [order]
inc r10
mov [counter], r10

.loop:
mov rdi, coeff_format
mov rsi, degree
mov rax, 2
;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    call    scanf       ;second call - works fine
;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
mov r8, [degree]
movsd   [poly_real+r8*8], xmm0
movsd   [poly_img+r8*8], xmm1
mov r10, [counter]
dec r10
mov [counter], r10
cmp r10, 0
ja  .loop       ;polynom

mov rdi, initial_format
mov rax, 2
;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    call    scanf       ;third call - segmentation fault
;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
movsd   qword[z_n_real], xmm0
movsd   qword[z_n_img], xmm1    ;initial

mov rdi, [order]
mov rsi, [poly_real]
mov rdx, [poly_img]
call    derivate

mov [deriv_img], rbx
mov [deriv_real], rax

ret
```

The error:

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007ffff7a6a4cf in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdbc8,
>     errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:2444
> ```

Comment: You don't set `rsi` for your first `scanf`, and you're incorrectly setting `AL=1` when you didn't actually *pass* any FP args in xmm0.  But it's not looking for any so that doesn't matter (unless you misaligned RSP and telling it there were FP args made it do 16-byte stores and crash).    Anyway, in C you did `scanf("blah blah %g");` with no `&epsilon` arg.

Comment: And BTW, you have some of the same bugs I commented on in [another question about this same assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958703/nasm-not-scaning-input-using-scanf#comment86944732_49958703), using qword loads into `r10` for `order` when you have a 32-bit `int` conversion (`%d`).  IDK why you're using `r10` for that, or why you keep your loop counter in memory instead of a call-preserved register like `ebx` or `r12d`.

Comment: The target is to get FP args. Doesn't scanf automatically storing the desired values in the xmm registers according to the number of FP variables mentioned in rax?

Comment: I tried to open a frame (using  `push rbp mov rbp rsp`) but got segmentation faults doing so. Can you please elaborate about the stack alignment pattern using scanf?

Comment: No, you pass `scanf` pointers, and it stores the results there.  If it returned multiple results, you'd write in C `(double a,double b, int i, int j) = scanf("%g%g%i%i");`.  But C isn't perl so that's not even valid syntax, and functions can only return a single value.  (And have a fixed return *type*.)  Unfortunately there's no way to do anything like what I wrote, except for a weak imitation of it by passing output pointer args, like you're already doing for integer conversions! The `scanf` you call from asm is the same machine-code function you call from C; look at compiler output.

Comment: Inside `get_input`, RSP is 16-byte aligned with no pushes, because you called it from `main` when `main` still had the stack 8 bytes away from aligned on function entry.  That's fine, your `get_input` is a private helper function so you can invent a custom calling convention where RSP is 16-byte aligned *after* a `call` instead of before, because that's the most convenient thing here.

Comment: Oh, I just realized why your first `scanf` doesn't fault: RSI still holds `argv` from entry into `main`.  So that's where you're storing the first `double` you convert.

Comment: The worst things happens when bugs are hiding behind other bugs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Now it works. What should i do? Post the working code and tag you? What's the convention?

Comment: Sure, post an answer if you want.  Unfortunately, I doubt anyone else with the same bug will know what to search on to find this.  That's why I only answered in comments instead of posting an answer.  (A less-generic title might help, though; I'll edit and post an answer now that we know what you thought scanf was going to do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You didn't pass a pointer arg for where to store FP conversion results.  You segfault on a `scanf` where `rsi` (the 2nd integer/pointer arg) holds garbage.  Just like if you'd written `scanf("%g");` in C.**

Your first scanf doesn't fault because RSI still holds `argv` from entry into main.  So that's where you're storing the first double you convert.

> The target is to get FP args. Doesn't scanf automatically storing the desired values in the xmm registers according to the number of FP variables mentioned in `rax`?

No, that's backwards and only works for *passing* FP args to functions, in the x86-64 SysV ABI.

You pass `scanf` *pointers*, and it stores the conversion results there. If it returned multiple results, you'd write in C

```
(double a,double b, int i, int j) = scanf("%g%g%i%i");
```

But C isn't perl; that's not even valid C syntax, and C functions can only return a single value.  (And have a fixed return type, so it can't be a struct with types that depend on the format string.)

Unfortunately there's no way to do anything like what I wrote in C, except for a weak imitation of it by passing output pointer args, like you're already doing for integer conversions!

**The `scanf` you call from asm is the same machine-code function you call from C; look at compiler output to  see how your C version compiles with actual pointer args.**

---

BTW, your idea of how `scanf`'s calling convention worked would be possible to implement in asm, but not easily because you can't index the register file.

You can't write a block of code that sets the `n`th XMM register except by branching, or self-modifying code.  On likely internal implementation would build an array in memory and then read it into registers with a fully-unrolled loop like `movsd xmm0, [rsp+0]` / `movsd xmm1, [rsp+8]` or whatever, and another array for integer return registers.

So this calling convention you were imagining for `scanf` would be convenient for the caller, but inconvenient for the callee, even moreso than dumping the XMM register args to an array it can index at the start of a variadic function when `al != 0` (that's what gcc actually does when compiling variadic functions, and why glibc `printf` segfaults if you call it with a misaligned stack and `al != 0`).

But that's not a real counter-argument, because it would be fine for non-variadic functions that return a fixed list values, just like the SysV calling convention's complex arg->register mapping is fine for normal functions and only inconvenient for variadic functions.

The real reason it doesn't work that way is that C doesn't support multiple return values, at all, ever.  You need to use output args, or struct returns.  A `struct` *can* actually be returned in multiple registers, though.